# Hive query with php thrift does not work

Tags: php, hadoop, thrift, hiveql

While running this code, stuck on  `$client->execute('SHOW DATABASES');` line.Libraries are on the proper directory but somehow we couldn't make query

```
 <?php
    $GLOBALS['THRIFT_ROOT'] = dirname(__FILE__) . '/lib';
    require_once $GLOBALS['THRIFT_ROOT'] . '/packages/hive_service/ThriftHive.php';
    require_once $GLOBALS['THRIFT_ROOT'] . '/transport/TSocket.php';
    require_once $GLOBALS['THRIFT_ROOT'] . '/protocol/TBinaryProtocol.php';

    require_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/ThriftHiveClientEx.php';

    $transport = new TSocket('localhost', 10001);
    $transport->setSendTimeout(30 * 1000);
    $transport->setRecvTimeout(30 * 1000);
    $client = new ThriftHiveClientEx(new TBinaryProtocol($transport));
    $client->open();

    print('open');
    //shell_exec('hive');
    $client->execute('SHOW DATABASES');
    print('database');
    var_dump($client->fetchAll());
    print('dump');
    $client->close();
    print('close');
```

Comment: "we couldn't" ... what symptoms, exception, error message You have?

Comment: There is no error output  while running the code but it is printing "open" but not printing "database". And it takes a little time after printing open and program is finished without running querry.

Comment: have you got any solution @challangerm

Comment: Yes sorry for not updating

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After closing SASL Authentication by adding a row our hive-site.xml,connection will be successful.